# Copying and Deleting charts from Excel to Word

Tags: excel, vba, charts, ms-word, shapes

My ultimate goal is to be able copy charts from Excel worksheets (16 in all), and paste them into a Word document at known bookmarks, Inline with the text. I do not want the Word file to link to the Spreadsheet for reasons I won't go into here. I then need to be able delete these same charts later on before copying a new set into the document.

It would seem that InLineShapes in Word do not have "Name" property, just an index, which I think has to be of type Long, not integer. When I click on a chart that I have copied, and use the Edit>Selection button on the Word Ribbon, it does show a name for each chart as Picture 1 etc.

I currently use the following code in the Excel workbook to copy and paste the charts into Word which seems to work fine.

```
This code will use Bookmarks to place the charts and copy them from this Workbook

        For i = 1 To 16

            Sheets(sheetnames(i)).Select
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(Chartlocn(i)).Activate
            ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
            

            With d.Bookmarks(Bookmarklocn(i)).Range
        
                .Select
                objW.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=15, Placement:=wdInLine, _
                DisplayAsIcon:=False
               
       
            End With
    
        Next i
```

and I have tried to use the following code to delete the charts:

```
 j = d.InlineShapes.Count
                
        counter = 0
        For i = 1 To d.InlineShapes.Count
    
            counter = counter + 1
            MsgBox (i)
            
                
            'If d.InlineShapes.Item(counter).Type = _
                'wdInlineShapePicture Then
                d.InlineShapes.Item(counter).Select
                objW.Selection.Delete Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 ' Came from Macro Recording
                
           ' Else
            'End If
            
        Next i
```

The commented out bits in the above did not work for me.

Despite checking everything I could imagine in the word file and Excel workbooks, each chart  seems to be the same - all inline, all sequentially "names" Picture x, same method to copy and paste.

But the observed behaviour is that some charts are deleted and some are not.

Is there a mechanism of identifying the charts in some way and then deleting them. I know that they have pasted at the bookmark locations. I am missing something obvious or is there a better way of copying and pasting so I can "get at" them later by some name or identifier?

Comment: `For i = j  To 1 Step -1   d.InlineShapes.Item(i).Delete` When deleting objects, loop backwards to avoid issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is delete all charts inside the active Word document using a `For` loop, you would probably need to loop starting from the highest index

```
For i = d.InlineShapes.Count to 1 Step -1
```

But it would be simpler and better to just use a `For Each` loop:

Eg.:

```vb
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Set WordApp = GetObject(, "Word.Application")

Dim chrt As Word.InlineShape
For Each chrt In WordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
    chrt.Delete
Next
```

---

And regarding having access to some kind of identifier to target a specific charts, I personnally like to use the `.AlternativeText` property which remains unchanged when you copy the chart over to Word.

Comment: Using a `For Each` loop to delete objects from a collection doesn't work because the implied counter doesn't get reset. That is why it is necessary to step through the collection backwards.

Comment: @TimothyRylatt I tested the code snippet provided in the question before posting and I can confirm that it does delete all InlineShapes. I'm assuming that the way the `For Each` loop passes the reference to the variable is not affected by counter/index issues. Maybe that's not the case for all VBA collections object. Do you have an example where it doesn't work?